SQL CROSS JOIN/Permutations to Rows Instead of Columns
I have the following table of bitmasks (this is a fraction/sample of the actual table. The data I am working with has many more bitmask columns).
bm1    bm2    bm3
-------------------------
0      0      0
1      0      0
0      2      0
0      0      4

I would like to do a CROSS JOIN (of sorts) to list all possible combinations. But I would like the results to be in rows, not columns. Like this:
bm1    bm2    bm3
-------------------------
0      0      0
0      2      0
0      0      4
1      0      0
1      2      0
1      0      4
0      2      4
1      2      4

The order of the columnar data must persist. i.e. bm1 can only be a 0 or 1, bm2 can only be 0 or 2, and bm3 can only be 0 or 4, etc.
Also, I am not committed to the original table of bitmasks. If there is a better approach to produce the desired resulting data, I am open to it.
How can this be accomplished?
Thank you!

This will generate all rows you want
with data(n) as (
    select level-1 connect by level <= power(2,3)
)
select n, 
    bitand(n,power(2,0)) as bm1, 
    bitand(n,power(2,1)) as bm2, 
    bitand(n,power(2,2)) as bm3
from data ;

but the order you show above corresponds to n sequence (0,2,4,1,3,5,6,7) while the result will be in natural order from 0 to 7.
0   0   0   0
1   1   0   0
2   0   2   0
3   1   2   0
4   0   0   4
5   1   0   4
6   0   2   4
7   1   2   4

